# I am unable to upgrade Ubuntu Impish to Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: upgrade

This is what I get when I execute following command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-egl-wayland1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnvidia-cfg1-470 libnvidia-common-470 libnvidia-compute-470
  libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-extra-470
  libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470
  nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-dkms-470 nvidia-driver-470
  nvidia-kernel-common-470 nvidia-kernel-source-470 nvidia-utils-470
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
16 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
16 standard security updates
Need to get 234 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2 392 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libnvidia-egl-wayland1
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 amd64 1:1.1.7-2build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
...
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: First of all, `dist-upgrade`, despite the name, will not upgrade your system to 22.04 or even try to. The command for that is `do-release-upgrade`.  https://linuxopsys.com/topics/difference-between-apt-get-upgrade-and-dist-upgrade Second, you need to fix all these problems before you try that. Please put the output of `apt policy libnvidia-egl-wayland1` into your question. However, I suspect the main problem you are having results from the fact that impish is EOL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above comments. I haven't realized that EOL versions require manual update to some scripts to upgrade. I have managed to upgrade now.